# Why is my code output always showing 0?

Tags: verilog, counter, system-verilog, quartus

This is a 4 bit counter code written using Verilog HDL on Quartus. Can somebody explain why is my output `o` always showing 0?

Code in Text :

```
module ab(i,o,r);
input i,r;
output [3:0]o;
counter4bit c4(i,o,r);
endmodule
module counter4bit(clk,y,reset);
input clk,reset;
output reg [3:0]y;

always@(posedge clk, posedge reset)
if (clk == 1)
y <= y + 1;

else if (reset == 1)
y <= 0; 

endmodule
```

If I write the reset condition first inside the `always` block it seems to run fine:

```
if (reset == 1)
            y <= 0;
            else if (clk == 1)
            y <= y+1; 
      )
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Make it easier for us to help you.  Edit your question and copy the code directly into it, not as a image, so that we can copy it.  Do you have testbench code as well?  If so, add that to your question.

Comment: @toolic I'm sorry I don't know what the "testbench code" is . I'm very new to this Verilog coding actually.

Comment: It's good that you posted your actual code now.  I added formatting for the code for you.  In the future, you should try to format it yourself.  I'm not familiar with Quartus tools; my guess is that it automatically creates a testbench for you so that you can run a simulation to generate those waveforms.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. From next time I will keep these things in mind.

Comment: @AkibAhmed I gather you want a clocked FF with an async reset? If so, you test the asynchronous reset signal first. Then, I think it can be synthesized. Otherwise? Do you know of an FF that checks its clock *before* an async reset? Maybe someone has built one. But I don't think it can be readily synthesized. (Probably can be simulated, though.)

Answer (score 4):

From your waveform image, it looks like your reset signal (`r`) is always 0.  Since you are not properly resetting your counter, I would expect the output to be unknown (`X`) instead of 0.  I can't explain why the waves show 0 because I am not familiar with Quartus tools.

However, you should really assign the reset signal to 1 at time 0, then assign it to 0 after a couple clock cycles (say at time 20ns).  This should properly reset the counter.

Your `always` block is not the traditional way to code a counter.  You should not check the clock signal inside the block that way.  The conventional way is as follows:

```
always @(posedge clk, posedge reset) begin
    if (reset == 1) begin
        y <= 0;
    end else begin
        y <= y + 1; 
    end
end
```